# Azure SQL Database pricing is per database server or per user-created database

Tags: azure-sql-database

For Azure SQL Database pricing, the pricing is mentioned as **$x/hour**

**Question:**  Let's say that 'x' is $2/hour. If I create 10 different user databases for my application, will I pay 10 times the hourly cost i.e. $20/hour or will I pay just $2/hour since the cost is for a database server?

I am not sure if I will be charged for each user-created database i.e. each of these 10 databases or just for one database server.

Comment: Very valid question. The pricing calculator suggests it to be per database, but since this would be such a spectacularly retarded pricing model, I still refuse to fully believe it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will be charged for each user-created database i.e. each of these 10 databases depending of their pricing tier.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/

Comment: The link you posted neither supports nor contradicts your claim.

Comment: As of 2015-12-23, it both supports and contradicts his claim, since it offers two pricing models, "Single Database" and "Elastic Database." Elastic Database, currently in preview, will "let you manage the collective performance of the pool rather than single databases. "

Comment: I agree that the documentation does not answer the question.  I did test this out myself and can confirm that the billing is per database, not database server.

Answer (score 7):

A new service plan was announced 04/2015, called SQL Azure Elastic database pool. As of today, it is still in preview mode, but pricing is available [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/) -- make sure you click on `Elastic Database` button to see the prices.

With Elastic database pool the pricing model is as follows. First, you pay per pool, based on number of performance units you reserve for the pool (DTUs). Then you pay additionally for each database, which is part of the pool. The per-database price is quite small (currently around $1.26/mo), so most of your expenses will be a payments for DTUs, that are shared across all databases of your pool.

### UPDATE:

As of May 2016, Azure SQL Database elastic pool is generally available. The [pricing details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/) are also updated. As of today, you can get up to 200 databases in Basic Tier for $149/month, which boils down to $0.745 per month per database.

Comment: Though it seems that `Elastic Database` cannot be considered as an alternative to `Single Database` as initial cost of `Elastic Database` is too high.

Comment: @ShyamalParikh, you might want to compare specific scenarios where database pool would make sense. E.g. 200 regular SQL Azure instances against an Elastic pool with 200 databases in it. With today's prices (01/17/2016) the 200 Basic Tier databases will run you $1000 per month, while Basic Tier of Elastic database with 100 eDTU's will run you $149 per month. So there are scenarios where Elastic databases are _much_ cheaper.

Comment: @ShyamalParikh I rcommend you to search a recording of one of my lectures about the topic where I show how we reduced the amount of resource units by `more then 90%` when we moved to the Elastic Pool! And to clarify I mean reduce by 90% and not to 90%, meaning that for each 100 units we now uses less than 10

Comment: Is this still accurate? I can't find any info on separate costs per db and per pool.

Answer (score 2):

The pricing for Azure SQL Database is per database. This means you would be paying for each of the 10 databases. You can learn more about [Azure SQL Database pricing here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/).

Comment: The link you posted neither supports nor contradicts your claim.